# Error message: undefined symbol _msize in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, turbo-c++

I m Writing program for dynamic memory allocation. In this program i getting error of undefined symbol _msize. I have also include .  Please help me with this.

```
/* Example of _msize */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void main()
{
 long *buffer;
 size_t size;

 buffer = (long *)malloc(100 * sizeof(long));
 size = _msize(buffer);
 printf("The size of the buffer is %d\n", size);
}
```

Comment: This is a non-portable thing from Microsoft. Are you using the MSVC compiler?

Comment: _msize() is not the standard function of C. It looks like home cooked stuff. You need to include the right header file in order to use that. Find _msize() in which header file it’s located. Side note: don’t use void main() that is not part of the C standard.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer..In <stdlib.h> header file, this function is already there. I have included that one also. http://www.digitalmars.com/rtl/stdlib.html#_msize

Comment: Is the header file you use meant to be used for the environment you use for building? I.e. matching compiler, all needed libraries linked implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: MSVC has `_msize` in `malloc.h` which you have included.

Comment: @Mat..I m using turbo c++ compiler..

Comment: 1. TurboC++ is an outdated antiquated product. 2. TurboC++ obviously doesn't have `_msize`. 3. `_msize` is not standard. 4. `_msize` isn't needed at all, you can do everything you want without it. 5. why is `_msize`not needed? Because _you_ allocated the buffer so you obviously know the size.

Comment: This is clearly a linker error and does not come from the compiler

Answer (score 2):

The `_msize` is *not* Standard C.

It is from [Microsoft Visual C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2s077bc.aspx)(MSVC), and you need to include `<malloc.h>`, as you already did, and use a Microsoft Compiler (e.g. within the Visual Studio).

---

PS: Unrelated to your problem: [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)